# How to modify a module required in Node.js before performing build?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Module **A.js (standard NPM package)**:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  const wsUrl = `ws://${window.location.hostname}:${window.location.port}/sockjs-node/websocket`;
  ...
};
```

Module **B.js**:

```
const a = require('A');
```

Is it possible to replace `${window.location.hostname}` & `${window.location.port}` in module A before performing build?

Comment: make the module a function and pass parameters into it ?

Comment: Module A is a standard NPM package, I'd like to use it directly, but not duplicate and  alter it.

Comment: @licaomeng that does not look like a worthwhile package to include in your project in the first place. If it doesn't even allow you to configure where it opens a connection, why not just rewrite the parts of the package you need into your project like has been suggested and stop using it?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I am intended to rewrite that piece of code. It is a trade-off, but not difficult to do.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to replace ${window.location.hostname} & ${window.location.port} in module A ?

it is not possible with your implementation.

Suggestion: it is better to have a configuration file that will hold you hostname and port

```
const HOSTNAME = process.env.HOSTNAME || window.location.hostname;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || window.location.port;
```

then the module A can just use the variable,

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It might help.

Module A.js

```
      exports.A = fucntion(window.location.hostname,window.location.port )
    {
        const wsUrl = `ws://${window.location.hostname}:${window.location.port}/sockjs-node/websocket`;
          return wsUrl;
        }
```

Module B.js

```
const a = require('A');
//then call the function A in module A.js
a.A(window.location.hostname,window.location.port);
```

Comment: Module A is a standard NPM package, I'd like to use it directly, but not duplicate and alter it.